# Python-social-auth returns admin user

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I am trying to setup python-social-auth to authenticate users from Vk. I have a standard setup as written in docs with normal pipeline. The problem is that when user tries to log in:

```
'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
```

always returns admin user. Basically, any user which tries to log in is associated with admin account. Any ideas why it happens and where to look at?!

Comment: You are probably logged in as admin so the social accounts are associated with admin

Comment: And you don't need to define a pipeline for standard setup. `social.backends.vk.VKOAuth2` in AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS, SOCIAL_AUTH_VK_OAUTH2_KEY and SOCIAL_AUTH_VK_OAUTH2_SECRET is enough.

Comment: actually not, every time I am testing pipeline i am logging out and restarting the session. Also for testing I have tried to open project in side browser - the result is the same. @MosesKoledoye

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev I have tried to remove SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE from settings. Anyway it returns me admin for any user which tries to log in.

Comment: The email address/username in VK is the same as the one used to setup django admin?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye no, usernames and emails are different. I have tried several Vk accounts

Answer (score 3):

Ok. I have found the answer. The problem was that I had already social auth association between UID and user which was recorded in DB. After removing the wrong association everything was working like a charm. Thanks to all who tried to help!